# How to plot a tibble onto Google Maps using ggmap?

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I am trying to plot the average price per bed on airbnb for 78 neighborhoods in a city. I was hoping to have the size of each point be based on the price.

The code I have been trying is:

```
Denver +
geom_point(data=lat, aes(latlong, latitude,size=priceperbed, color=neighbourhood_cleansed))+
 geom_text_repel(data=lat, aes(label = neighbourhood_cleansed), color='green')+
guides(color=FALSE)
```

The error message says: object "lon" not found. I don't have "lon" anywhere in the code, and have not been able to debug this one.

lat is a tibble with columns "long", "latitude", "priceperbed", and "neighbourhood_cleansed"
Each column is the average, so average longitude, latitude, and price per bed by neighbourhood.

"Denver" is the map I generated from ggmap

EDIT: @RichardTelford thank you for your help. I tried using the following code but I received an error message each time.

`Denver +
  geom_point(data=lat, aes(long, latitude,size=priceperbed, color=neighbourhood_cleansed, inherit.aes=FALSE))+
  geom_text_repel(data=lat, aes(label = neighbourhood_cleansed), color='green', inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  guides(color=FALSE)`

This what I received from that:
`Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: inherit.aes
Error: geom_text_repel requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y`

`Denver +
  geom_point(data=lat, aes(long, latitude,size=priceperbed, color=neighbourhood_cleansed, inherit.aes=FALSE))+
  geom_text_repel(data=lat, aes(label = neighbourhood_cleansed), color='green')+
  guides(color=FALSE)`

This what I received from that:
`Warning: Ignoring unknown aesthetics: inherit.aes
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'lon' not found`

`Denver +
  geom_point(data=lat, aes(long, latitude,size=priceperbed, color=neighbourhood_cleansed))+
  geom_text_repel(data=lat, aes(label = neighbourhood_cleansed), color='green', inherit.aes=FALSE)+
  guides(color=FALSE)`

This what I received from that:
`Error: geom_text_repel requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y`

EDIT: @Chris

Here is my data for lat

`head(lat)
         neighbourhood_cleansed latitude      long priceperbed
1                   Athmar Park 39.70341 -105.0130    49.53000
2                       Auraria 39.74944 -105.0044   114.40000
3                         Baker 39.71927 -104.9932    76.38110
4                        Barnum 39.71878 -105.0354    37.29545
5                   Barnum West 39.72107 -105.0443    21.31746
6                   Bear Valley 39.66221 -105.0663    51.24074`

This is the code I used to create my ggmap:

`Denver <- get_map("Denver", zoom=11) %>%
ggmap()`

I tried adding `geom_text_repel(data=lat, aes(long, latitude, label = neighbourhood_cleansed), color='green')` into my code.

It returned most of the map that I was looking for, but I received the following error message:

`Warning messages:
1: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_point). 
2: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_text_repel). 
3: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
4: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
5: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
6: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf`

Comment: try adding `inherit.aes = FALSE` to the geom_point/geom_text

Comment: I can't reproduce your error. It would help if you posted your data for `lat` and the code used to create your `ggmap`. Looking at your code there may be a typo with your second line `aes(latlong...)` which you say is just called `long` in the text. You should also add in the X,Y aethetics into `geom_text_repel` - `aes(long, latitude,label = neighbourhood_cleansed)`.